# Eclipse/pydev won't import mysql.connector with a project, but imports fine from IDLE

Tags: python, mysql, eclipse, pydev

I'm attempting to do the mysql tutorial for the python connector.

Using Xubuntu 14.04, python3, mysql 5.5.35, eclipse Luna and pydev 3.6.0. I installed the python.connector via instructions on the mysql website.

When I use python 3 from the command line into the interactive shell, I can do

```
import mysql.connector
```

just fine. I can then proceed to do things with that import, for example all the following code runs fine:

```
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='root', host='127.0.0.1',database='testdb')
>>> cnx.close()
```

In eclipse, I am unable to import it properly, but I still have a red 'squiggly' with `unresolved import` errors. As such I'm unable to use autocomplete for any of my script. . I've set up my interpreter to use python3 (as well as the python 3.4 option, tried separately).

On the left, I can see mysql under `python > System Libs > python3/dist-packages > mysql` as part of my project

[image]

[image]

My interpreter is set up as such:

[image]

Regardless of what I do, I am unable to get it to import in eclipse. I've tried the answers here to no avail:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3864323/3665278

[How do I handle an UnresolvedImport Eclipse (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2451682/3665278)

https://stackoverflow.com/q/27897035

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on Mac OS X and found that the python connector binary install did not work.  Instead, I installed the 'Platform Independent' TAR from

```
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/
```

and ran

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

as instructed.  This put the connector code into the site-packages and then

```
import mysql.connector
```

started working.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10 64 bit. I first checked if 32 or 64 bit python installed and used appropriate .msi which in my case was 32.